# same identifier for type and object in declaration

Tags: c++, c, naming-conventions, variable-declaration, function-definition

I stumbled upon a function implementation that recycles a type name for a parameter of the same type. The code compiles and seems to do exactly what's intended. Here a minimized version:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct X {
    int v;
};

void print_X(const X& X)   // <--- here the identifier X has *two different meanings*
{
    cout << "X.v:" << X.v << endl;
}
```

The code was developed against Borland C++ 5.6.4

I tried several different and more up-to-date compilers:

- C++11 (mingw32-g++ 4.9.2, shipped with CodeBlocks 16.01)
- [C++ (gcc 6.3)](http://ideone.com/NvnVsK)
- [C++14 (gcc 6.3)](http://ideone.com/m9BWrX)
- [C++ 4.3.2 (gcc 4.3.2)](http://ideone.com/KIO12f)
- [C++14 (clang 4.0)](http://ideone.com/XFw6eN)

All accept it without complaining.

I don't think it's good C++, but...

**Is it valid C++? And, if yes, will it be valid in future?**

#### Update

How horrifying! Only now I see, that the same is true for a simple variable declaration:

```
X X;
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/a9GM49

#### Update #2

C++ shares this feature with the C language:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct X {
    int v;
} X;

int main()
{
    X X;
    X.v = 7;
    printf("X.v:%d\n", X.v);
    return 0;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/nheZTa

Comment: It is valid C++. Whether it is good C++ is up for debate.

Comment: @Ron I have the strong feeling that it can be really bad and [tried to illustrate that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45504734/2932052).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's valid. You are declaring a variable (parameter) in an inner scope that hides the name from an outer scope.

Of course not a great idea in this case.

Comment: the irony: it prevents you from using a second parameter of the same type, so you cannot mix them in function calls ;-)

Comment: I find it hard to find a **readable reference** for this. And, I'm just seeing it: also `X X;` seems to be valid. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I found also `struct X { int v; }; X X;` to be valid code. So hiding names seems not to be restricted to scope changes ...

Answer (score 2):

It is valid. It hides the variable from the outer scope. Hiding like this is usually called *shadowing* and your compiler probably has a warning you can enable to tell you when it is happening (gcc has `-Wshadow`).

Here's another example :

```
int x; // global variable - always accessible as ::x
int main(int x, char** argv) { // this 'x' hides global 'x'
    // This is the only place you can get at the argument 'x'
    // before it is hidden by the line below.
    int x; // this subsequently hides the function argument 'x'
    {
        int x; // hides the 'x' at function scope
        for (int x = 0; x < 42; ++x) { // this 'hides 'x' in our nested scope
            // The for loop induction variable 'x' is what's in scope here
        }
        // Now 'x' is again the nested-scope 'x'
    }
    // Here 'x' again refers to the function scope 'x'
}
// At any point in time you can get access to the 'x' that is directly
// in scope *or* the global 'x' (as '::x')
// But you cannot access the other 'x's until you are back in
// their respective scopes.
```

But try to avoid doing things like the above. It quickly leads to confusion and bugs.

Comment: Okay, this demonstrates hiding of objects. But well, hiding deals in general with identifiers.

Comment: to know the term *shadowing* and the switch `-Wshadow` is definitely helpful, but the interesting thing is that *names are hidden*, not just *variables* -- the fact that code may change its meaning after an object name shadows a type name is extremely confusing ...

Answer (score 1):

By doing that, you hide the global name inside the function block.

```
void print_X(const X& X, const X& Y)  //won't compile

void print_X(const X& X){
   X myX;    //again, won't compile
}
```

In Stroustrup words:<sup>*</sup>

> A declaration of a name in a block can hide a declaration in an
>   enclosing block or a global name. That is, a name can be redefined to
>   refer to a different entity within a block. After exit from the block,
>   the name resumes its previous meaning.

---

<sup>*</sup> Stroustrup: The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition; Section 6.3.4 Scope; Page 157

Comment: I think the above code is a poor illustration for bad effects in hiding since **it doesn't compile**. It also can have [nice side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45503217/same-identifier-for-type-and-object-in-declaration#comment77967414_45503340)

Comment: Besides the example, can you add a link to the quote? I read your answer again and found the quote part useful (code sometimes can also be distracting). I tried to find the source, but without luck. Would you please add a link to the quote, then I'd like to vote for it ...

Comment: Excerpt from C++ Programming Stroustrup 4th Edition book

Comment: Thanks so far. Can you also add chapter and page number?

Comment: Section 6.3.4 Scope;  Page 157